# Is umount performed automatically during a reboot?

Tags: usb, reboot, umount

Let's say I have a USB device mounted. When issuing a system restart using the command line utility "reboot", will the system automatically umount my USB device?

Also, typically, if any shell is up with its current directory open to the mount point then the device cannot be "umount"ed. In the reboot scenario, what happens in this case? The same thing?

If you can, please provide an answer with references to back up your claims.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure on `reboot` command, however I do know for sure that `shutdown -P now` will perform automatic umount on system shutdown.

References aren't provided. But you can just trust strangers on the internet.

EDIT: Just found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12767/does-shutdown-p-now-safely-unmount-a-usb-drive-mounted-to-dev-sdb1) reference, maybe more strangers agreeing with me will provide you with more confidence.

Comment: I think that post is what I am looking for. I'm going to move my activity there instead. Thanks!